# How to get current row of datagridview values when clicking on button?

Tags: c#, winforms, button, datagridview, rowdatabound

I have a View Model in which my data is stored to be used on the presenter and window. However, I now need to get (when pressing a button) the current row's results on the grid into my view model. I first used the mouse double click event, but the requirements changed from that to a button on the form:

```
private void dgvResults_CellMouseDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
    {
       if (this.colOrderNo.Index != e.ColumnIndex || e.RowIndex < 0) return;

       var auditOrder = (PurchaseOrdersTrackingViewModel) this.dgvResults.Rows[e.RowIndex].DataBoundItem;
       this.AuditOrderKey = $"{auditOrder.OrderNo}|{auditOrder.ItemNo}|{auditOrder.WarehouseId}|{auditOrder.ItemSequence}";
    }
```

That's my old code. Now I need that here:

`private void btnAuditLog_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)`

Not sure how to refer to the `RowIndex` without the `DataGridViewCellMouseEventArges` event. I tried the `CurrentRow` property, but it doesn't do the job.

Just another question on the fly, if someone could assist with that as well, how do I get a value from one form to another, spesifically a properties value. It's not on the grid, in a control. It's basically just `public string order` that's all. I set the value on one form, then need it for query filtering on another. Let me know if you need anything else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use the SelectedRows property of the DataGridView.  It tells which row is selected.  In this case, you seem to want the first selected row (since you have a single property called this.AuditOrderKey).

The column order no to longer matters in this context.

```
 if (dgvResults.SelectedRows.Count == 0) return;

 var auditOrder = (PurchaseOrdersTrackingViewModel) dgvResults.SelectedRows[0].DataBoundItem;
 this.AuditOrderKey = $"{auditOrder.OrderNo}|{auditOrder.ItemNo}|{auditOrder.WarehouseId}|{auditOrder.ItemSequence}";
```

If you don't have selected rows, CurrentRow is an option:

```
 if (dgvResults.CurrentRow == null) return;

 var auditOrder = (PurchaseOrdersTrackingViewModel) dgvResults.CurrentRow.DataBoundItem;
 this.AuditOrderKey = $"{auditOrder.OrderNo}|{auditOrder.ItemNo}|{auditOrder.WarehouseId}|{auditOrder.ItemSequence}";
```

Comment: Any idea on the property value being carried from one class to another?

Comment: if you have an instance of your form, then it would be instancename.dgvResults (you might need to change the modifier of dgvResults to public if its not already).

Comment: I have a problem with that. The `SelectionMode` is set to `RowHeaderSelect` which I am not allowed to change, to keep the application consistent. So technically, there is no selected row.

Answer (score 0):

Use the SelectedRows property of the DataGridView. Assuming that you set your DataGridView as MultiSelect = false; and SelectionMode = FullRowSelect;

```
if (dgvResults.SelectedRows.Count > 0)
{
   dgvResults.SelectedRows[0].Cells["yourColumnName"].Value.ToString();
}
```

In your button click event, it will look like this. (Assuming that your button name is btnEdit)

```
private void btnEdit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (dgvResults.SelectedRows.Count > 0)
    {
       string selectedValue = dgvResults.SelectedRows[0].Cells["yourColumnName"].Value.ToString();
    }
}
```